# How to use Ajax to update Button in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

So here's my dilemma, I am new to rails, and have come across a scenario where I'd like to use AJAX.  I've never used AJAX before, but need to learn it.

So I have created a simple web page that displays current time.  I want to have a button on the page that when clicked, updates the current time using AJAX.  I have done all my work in the view, and am sure that I missing something somewhere, but not sure what it is, like I don't know where in the controller I would place additional code to make this work.  Again, it's just a real simple code that I'm just trying to learn one function with.

Here is my code:

```
<h1>Time#index</h1>

<div id="time">

The current time is <%= Time.now  %>

</div>

<br>

<br>




<%= form_tag("/search", method: "get") do %>

  <%= label_tag(:q, "Press button to update time:") %>

  <%= submit_tag("Update") %>

<% end %>

<p>Find me in app/views/time/index.html.erb</p>
```

Any idea where to go from here to actaully get the time to update using AJAX?  I copied the form tag from a search function, so please don't pay attention to the names, just functionality.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you create a Times controller:

```
# app/controllers/times_controller.rb
class TimesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @time = Time.now

    # edit: I forgot to add this before, I think this will solve it.
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

Wire this up in the routes:

```
# config/routes.rb
YourAppsName::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :times, only: :index
end
```

Change the view you currently have to this (its a bit simpler using just a link instead of a form):

```
<h1>Time#index</h1>

<div id="time">
  The current time is <%= Time.now  %>
</div>
<br>
<br>

<%= link_to 'Update Time', times_path, remote: true %>

<p>Find me in app/views/time/index.html.erb</p>
```

Notice that `remote: true`, this will tell Rails to perform an AJAX request when the link is clicked. The request will go to the index action of the TimesController. Now add this js.erb template to handle the response and update the time in the view:

```
# app/views/times/index.js.erb
$('#time').html("The current time is <%= @time %>");
```

That will update the time.

Here's some further reading:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=11

Happy ajaxing!

Comment: Diego, Thanks so much for your help and quick response!!  I really appreciate it.

Comment: Diego, it's has one functional problem.  When I click the link it doesn't update the time displayed where it says "the current time is"

Comment: So basically what I want to happen when I click the link "Update Time" is that the time is actually updated in the area between the <div>

Comment: I don't follow, isn't the area between the div the place you want to update? can you post what it looks like and what you'd want it to look like?

Comment: Diego, I won't be able to send you a screen shot until tomorrow.  I'm at work and don't have my laptop with me today.  That said, the code is just how you have it, I copied it word for word.  The problem is that the link doesn't refresh the page.  So when the page first comes up it displays the current time.  "The current time is ...."  What I want to do is when the link "Update Time" is clicked, I want the time that was first displayed when opening the page to change to the current time.  As it is now, clicking the link "Update Time" does not do anything as far as the page is concerned.

Comment: You are further confusing me, in your previous comment you stated "that the time is actually updated in the area between the <div>". Now you're saying "clicking the link "Update Time" does not do anything as far as the page is concerned". 

When you click the link does your server log show anything? An error maybe? Keep in mind that the page is not supposed to refresh, that's the point of AJAX. But you should see activity in your rails server log.

Comment: Diego, sorry for the confusion.  Let me start over a little.  So when the page initially loads you see the statement "the current time is xxxx" (xxxx being the actual time) and you also see the link "Update Time" below that.  The statement "the current time is xxx" is in the <div>, the update link is outside of the <div>.  Now, when I click the "update time" link, I want the current time that is displayed between the <div> to be updated.

Comment: I understand that part, but not what's going wrong. 

1) Does your server log show any activity when you click the update time link?

2) Can you check the Firebug console (or Chrome dev tools, whatever inspector is in your browser) for any activity when you click on the link? You should see an ajax call in the console or network activity in the network tab.

Comment: What is going wrong is that the time doesn't update, it just stays the same time as it was on the initial opening of the page.  I will check tonight and get back to you in regards to the server log (I don't have my laptop with me).  Thanks for hanging in there and trying to help me out.

Comment: No problem. I updated the controller code in the answer with something that i missed that might fix the problem.